# dd($request->country_flag); returns null in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

This is my form to upload a file:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
<form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.country.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="country_id">Country ID</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="country_id" name="country_id">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="country_name">Country name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="country_name" name="country_name">
        <p class="danger">{{ $errors->first('country_name') }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="alternate_title">Alternate Title</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="alternate_title" name="alternate_title">
        <p class="danger">{{ $errors->first('alternate_title') }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="country_flag">Country Flag</label>
        <input class="" type="file" id="country_flag" name="country_flag">
        <p class="danger">{{ $errors->first('country_flag') }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="reset">Reset</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Upload</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is a function in my controller to handle form request.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $new_country = new SelectCountry();
    $message = [
        'required' => "This field can not be empty",
    ];

    $this->validate($request, [
        'country_name' => 'required',
        'alternate_title' => 'required',
        'country_flag' => 'required',
    ], $message);

    dd($request->country_flag);
}
```

When I do `dd($request->country_flag);`, it returns `null`. It seems like file is not uploaded by the form.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can or not access a file like you are doing. Try this:

`$file = $request->file('country_flas');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$input = $request->all();
$file = $input['country_flag'];
dd($file);
```